# How to use include function in another custom function?

Tags: smarty

I am using Smarty 3.1.8

I want to include a tpl file only one time on page even if tpl file called more times.I dont know that I can do the that with Smarty without write a new custom function.So I think to write a new custom include function for this.

Can I use include function of smarty in the custom include function ?

I want to use smarty include function in my the custom include function for compile given template. 
How am I do this ?

I want to use as follow :

```
{include_js file="script.users.tpl"}
```

Comment: Maybe I just don't quite understand your question, but a template isn't something that you just 'include once'. It's just a blueprint for the representation of your data, and then you apply the data to it. So I don't quite get what you mean with including a template file...

Comment: Sorry I know little english.So I did not explain exactly that what I want.If I can compile template in include_js function that given to the include_js function as parameter, I will be check the template is loaded before and if template is loaded before, I wont be include template again.Do you understand me ?

Comment: I guess I know what you mean now: You want to pass a template-name to the function `include_js($template_name)`, and within the function, you want to check if this template has been rendered before, otherwise render it now. Well, yes, that is quite possible, but it would be helpful to know your coding language or to see some code... The pattern is quite simple: Save the template to a (sort of global) variable (like `$tmpl_1 = $smarty->fetch(...);` in PHP) and then, within `include_js()`, just check whether the variable is set or not. I hope this answers your question somehow.

Comment: On the other hand, if your goal is some kind of performance improvement, keep in mind that Smarty already does some caching for you. It even provides an `is_cached()` function... (I can't post the URL here because the documentation page seems to be having some issues right now, but you can just google "smarty cache" and check out the first results.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP? If, so try this:
Even though it's in Smarty, use the php **include_once("/dir/filename");** function.

using smarty_bc or smarty2:

**{some_smarty.tpl}**

```
<html>
    <p>ex paragraph one</p>
    <p>ex paragraph two</p>
    {php} include_once("script.users.tpl"); {/php}
</html>
```

This way you can rely on having PHP monitor that the file is only being inserted once.

Comment: Php cant use in tpl files directly,so I wrote a smarty function and I am checking the given path within function.If tpl file not included I am rendering an pushing it to html.I think this is best way. `{include_once file="user_scripts.tpl"}`

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the answer to reflect your comments.  If that doesn't work for you, you may need a static class that keeps track on whether it has been called or not and returns a blank value if it has already been used.

Comment: Thanks for advice @ RightHandedMonkey. Using a static class is applicable but I think using a smarty function better method.